# What are the correct translations and pronunciations for "It's a lot, isn't it?"

Tags: translation, pronunciation

I came across [this sample](https://soundcloud.com/jondice-1/itsalotisntit) for the above phrase; when I [tried it on google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%EB%A7%8E%EC%A7%80%20%EC%95%8A%EB%82%98%EC%9A%94%3F), I got 많지 않나요 ... which might be right, I suppose - it looks close, but Google translate seems off. Obviously in the first word for "a lot", but in the second word, in the recording I posted, it sounds like it should start with a "ᅵ" and not an "ᅡ" sound. Also of note, I couldn't find these words on Forvo ([for example](https://forvo.com/search/%EC%95%8A%EB%82%98/)).

Comment: the recording says 많이 있네요

Comment: In addition, 많이 있네요 is not a question. I would use "많죠?" (pronunciation: 만ː초) to mean that question. Forvo has recordings for the words that have ever been asked to pronounce. Since a large number of Koreans use YouTube, [YouGlish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%EB%A7%8E%EC%A3%A0%20%3F/korean) will help although captions are not all correct (for example, the subtitle may be a translation or automatically created caption; it may have typing errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted the literal meaning one, it would be “많지 않아요?”

However in the daily living lifestyle, there are many phrases that refers to the same meaning of “it’s a lot, isn’t it”.

E.g.

- 이거 많네요. (Speaker has a surprised feeling)
- 이거 많은데요? (Speaker has a surprised feeling and wants to express it contrasting from other person that would have said that it’s not a lot)
- 이거 많아요. 안 그래요? (Speaker wants the listener idea about the thing)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use another translator at the same time.

https://papago.naver.com/?sk=en&tk=ko&hn=0&st=It%25%2339s%20a%20lot%2C%20isn%25%2339t%20it%3F%E2%80%9D

```
많잖아, 안 그래?
```

When I translate Korean to English, google translator is a bit nicer. but Eng->Kor case, the Papago would be better to use.